# MacOS Monterey (12.3) and Apache 2.53 https does not connect

Tags: https, mac-osx, apache2

On macOS Monterey (12.3.1) and Apache 2.53 (homebrew) I always receive (on Firefox)

```
"Secure Connection Failed"

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Other browsers will not connect as well. No error message in apache logs and access_log records this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2022:21:12:37 +0300] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 226
```

when trying https://localhost. While http: works fine

I even tried to uninstall homebrew Apache and used embedded Apache with the same result

I recently upgraded from El Capitan (everything was fine there) and initially tried to use same Apache configs, then I googled the entire internet but found nothing that helps

Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what action was the last one but after computer restart localhost open on https with "connection not secure" notification, but it connects now! The certificate errors is not a problem for testing purpose. So, Apache restart is not enough sometimes!